# static_cast from 'const char *' to 'void *' is not allowed

Tags: c++, casting, c-strings

In C++, I'm trying to print the address of a C-string but there seems to be some problem with my cast. I copied the code from a book but it just doesn't compile on my mac.

```
const char *const word = "hello";
cout << word << endl; // Prints "hello"
cout << static_cast< void * >(word) << endl;  // Prints address of word
```

Comment: `static_cast` cannot remove `const`. Either cast to `void const*` or use an additional `const_cast` to remove the `const` separately.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You are trying to cast away "constness": `word` points to constant data, but the result of `static_cast<void*>` is not a pointer to constant data. [`static_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast) will not let you do that.

You should use `static_cast<const void*>` instead.

Comment: Why does it print the address of word when we type cast it to const void *?

Comment: @Lincoln, `cout << X` does something different depending on the type of `X`. Since `char*` and `const char*` are often used to represent textual data, the C++ standard guys decided that when X is a `char*` or a `const char*`, it should print characters that it points to. However, `void*` and `const void*` are basically meaningless (it could be anything), so the standard guys decided that the most convenient thing to do would be to print the address.

Answer (score 0):

There is a demo

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    void* Name1;
    Name1 = static_cast<void*>(new std::string("Client 1"));

    void* Name2;
    std::string str1 = "Client 2";
    Name2 = &str1;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).